# QtQuick 2 window resize not refreshing elements

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm new to QtQuick 2 development and currently learning layouts.
In my application I simply have 3 rectangles I'm placing in a column layout.

- A "header" rectangle at the top with height 30
- A "footer" rectangle at the bottom with height 30
- A "body" rectangle in between to fill up the remaining space

When I maximize the window on Windows 10 by snapping the application window to the top of screen, everything resizes correctly, however the "old" footer rectangle remains where it used to be. I noticed it stays there until I click a button or execute some action that forces the UI to finally refresh and erase where the footer used to be. So when I place something like an indeterminate progressbar in the application, the issue goes away.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    minimumHeight:500
    minimumWidth:1300
    height: 500
    width: 1300
    //visibility: Window.Maximized
    title: qsTr("layout practice")

    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle{
            id:header
            height: 30
            color:"black"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
            Layout.preferredHeight: 30
            Layout.maximumHeight: 30
            Layout.minimumHeight: 30
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Rectangle{
            id:body
            color:"blue"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            Button {
                id: button
                x: 36
                y: 200
                text: qsTr("Button")
            }

            //            ProgressBar{
            //                x: 36
            //                y: 118
            //                width:100
            //             height:10
            //             indeterminate: true
            //            }
        }

        Rectangle{
            id:footer
            height: 30
            color:"grey"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignBottom
            Layout.preferredHeight: 30
            Layout.maximumHeight: 30
            Layout.minimumHeight: 30
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }   
    }
}
```

Before maximizing: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jblUnaMdMV1Sc3uMJI96fQ57j75zzZso

[image]

After maximizing:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1osIszI6utIWlRziaiFW38jxlpgriTOH4

[image]

How do I avoid this? How would I force a refresh when the window height is changed?

Comment: So in your screenshot after resizing, there is a ghost of the old footer's position and the footer also correctly positionned? BTW you could use QQC2's ApplicationWindow instead of Window, it has a `header` and a `footer` property. You could get rid of your `ColumnLayout`.

Comment: Facing the same issue. On window resize, the button/text moves to the correct position but a "copy" of it remains in its old position. It goes away after performing some UI action like clicking the button.
This behavior doesn't happen in the examples though.

Comment: @GrecKo, Thanks for the input. I tried using ApplicationWindow's header/footer properties, and still getting the same result. A ghost of the footer remains until some UI action. Also, I noticed when using the header/footer properties in ApplicationWindow, the header and footer do not appear in the design view. Any idea how to make them visible?